# How can I choose who of the tabindex="0" start when the page load

Tags: html, css

**Important note:** all the indexes must be 0 (tabindex="0"), I can not use another numbers (like: tabindex="1",tabindex="2"...tabindex="n").

for example: my html code is:

```
<div tabindex="0">first</div>
<div tabindex="0">second</div>
<div tabindex="0">third</div>
<div tabindex="0">Etc...</div>
```

Now - I want to focus on the second div by default, so when I click on Tab - the focus will be on third div, and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery `next` function to get next sibling.

Here you have working example: https://jsfiddle.net/2muaxbbf/

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("div[tabindex='0']").eq(1).focus();


});
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div tabindex="0">first</div>
<div tabindex="0">Second</div>
<div tabindex="0">third</div>
<div tabindex="0">Etc...</div>
</body>
</html>
```